# Change 'Open in iBooks' to something useful?

Tags: ios, safari, pdf, books

Older versions of Safari/iOS remembered the last used PDF viewer, or at least displayed my preferred one automatically e.g. at the top in the PDF preview of safari, 'Open in PDFExpert or so.
With the introduction of iBooks -- which is lacking annotation, dropbox, and other crucial features for working with scientific articles etc. -- the default has become the annoying self-promotional 'Open in iBooks' with apparently no way to change it to something useful.

I've reported this as a bug to Apple, but while waiting for the unlikely fix, has anyone figured out a way to change the default 'Open in' to something useful or at least move iBooks to the end of the icon list in the Open In menu? It seems to come back to the front all the time.

Comment: and you have to use Safari to access those files online?

Comment: its Apple, who coded for themselves, of course they will have luxuries other developers don't have, and of course they will prioritize their own software compared to 3rd parties, you can't change this function